# How to make the tooltip point to the center of the widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to show the tooltip above the text tile like this. I don't know how to make the little triangle in UI point to the center of the text.

[image: required goal]

I am using tutorial_coach_mark flutter package for this. This is my tooltip widget:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.f3146FF,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(scaleRadius(8, context)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CustomText(
                  text: 'Record $text',
                  textStyle: CustomTextStyle.textStyle16SemiBold(context),
                ),
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  AppAssets.icCrossIcon,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CustomText(
              text: 'Make it faster by recording ${text?.toLowerCase()}',
              textStyle: CustomTextStyle.textStyle14Medium(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: text == "Video"
              ? scaleWidth(120, context)
              : scaleHeight(280, context),
        ),
        child: SvgPicture.asset(AppAssets.tooltip),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

I don't know how to put the triangle above the text, so I added static padding `left: text == "Video" ? 120 : 280` which is working fine in my device but this is not a good solution and will not work properly in other devices. I want a generic way to do this. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have two options:

1. Use `GlobalKey`s for your "Text", "Video" and "Audio" elements to track their position and slightly shift the triangle higher;
2. If you know the exact position of elements (or at least you can calculate it) - you can try to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or `.height` to access the device's screen size and adjust `Padding` based on that information.